# Howto distribute outbound traffic in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, traffic, distribute

how jmeter can distribute outbound traffic between the two user groups. For example the group #1 gets 30% of the traffic and the group #2 of 70%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your requirement as Oliver did, for me you just setup a Thread Group with 30% of the total threads and the second one with 70%.

Otherwise, you can read this article with is another way to do the way Oliver understood:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_control_percentage_of_sampler/

It shows how to distribute but contrary to  Throughput Controller it ensures at least one sample is executed.

Comment: Changed "Number of Threads" to 50% in Thread Group, but tests stopped starting.

Comment: Hello, when i say 50%, i mean if you have 500 total users, put 250 as value , is it what you did ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can do this. You could use a [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) which is pretty simple, or, if you only ever want one request to fire, you could create a simple [Random Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable), set it as a random number between 0 and 10 and then use an [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to control execution.

Something like:

```
Thread Group
    - Random Variable 0 - 10
    - If Controller set to ${myVar} <= 3
        HTTP Sampler
    - If Controller set to ${myVar} > 3
        HTTP Sampler
```